# Swift.Extensions var and func. Which one is better?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I'm a beginner.
Here's the code

```
extension Double  {
    func abs1() -> Double  {
        return ( self > 0 ) ? self : -1.0 * self
    }

    var abs2 : Double {
        return ( self > 0 ) ? self : -1.0 * self
    }
}
```

I would like to know, what's the difference between abs1() function and abs2 variable, how do they work and which one is better?

Comment: They do the same thing and should have similar (if not identical) performance characteristics. It mostly boils down to whether you consider the absolute value of a number a property of that number.

Comment: for better reading its better func, its more clear and logical, but technically both works for the same in this case

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are the same in how they work. It really is a signal of intent. Personally I would recommend the function in this case, which is slightly counter-intuitive, so I'll explain.

The first rule is "does it have side effects?" If so, it should be a function.

The second rule is "is it O(1)?" (That means "it takes a constant, and generally assumed to be short, period of time to run." In other words, is it "cheap?") If not, it should be a function.

But the third, more subtle rule is "is it reasonably considered a "property" of the instance?" And in this case I'd argue, no. It is a completely different thing than the instance. It is something *computed* on the instance, not something that is an intrinsic *part* of the instance. It would be fairly ridiculous for this to be replaced with a non-computed property (you'd never store "4" as the "abs" field of "-4"). So I would make it a function.

Note that in Swift 3, `abs` is a static function on the type (for example, it's `Double.abs(4.0)` rather than `(4.0).abs`). That doesn't invalidate your question, but given this *specific* case, that's how the team chose to address it, and I think it's a better way.

Comment: +1. I have always used them as properties *when it makes sense* but I like the other two criteria you have to consider whether it should be a function or a calculated property. It makes perfect sense to consider it a property when it doesn't have side effects and when it is "cheap".

Comment: Just a note:  the static `abs()` method on `Double` is part of its conformance to the `AbsoluteValuable` protocol, which is an optional way for signed number types to provide customized implementations to the global `abs()` function. I'm not sure it's really a preferred way to implement methods which operate on an instance in general, or that it's really meant to be called directly that way at all. Really liked the guidelines in your answer (and upvoted it), but I think it may be incorrect to model this kind of function as a static method unless required to conform to a protocol.

Comment: Agreed that it shouldn't be called directly this way, but for abs specifically, the preferred way is the free function `abs()`. Free functions are very unusual in Swift, and you're right that abs is a somewhat poor thing to use as a model for APIs generally.