# Swift - Structs - Static var vs static func

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I've the habit to always create a Config file where I declare some stuff that I need to reuse for the whole app (colors, some other specific things...). In Swift the things are different from Objective C, so I decided to use structs for this. But now I'm struggling to understand which of these 2 ways is the better one to use :

```
struct Config {

        struct Colors {

            static func main () -> UIColor {
                return UIColor.red
            }

            static func secondary () -> UIColor {
                return UIColor.yellow
            }

            static let mainVar = UIColor.red
            static let secondaryVar = UIColor.yellow
        }
    }
```

The difference between the two is clear : some are functions (static), others are vars. Which one is the right approach to provide this kind of information (information which doesn't need params to be set)?

Comment: I would consider making those `struct`s case-less `enum`s instead, as it prevents accidental initialisation (e.g `let c = Config()`).

Comment: Strictly spoken the *var* equivalent is `static let mainVar...`. You should use computed properties only if there **is** something to compute.

Comment: Related: [What is the preferred way of getting value in swift, var vs. func?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747338/what-is-the-preferred-way-of-getting-value-in-swift-var-vs-func)